# USB hub with standalone charging support

Tags: usb, android, hub

**Background:**

I am a android developer. In some phases of the development process I have to look how the layouts/app looks on different phones. Therefore you can attach all phones to a usb-hub and deploy the changes to all devices simulatinously.

**Problem**

The company I am working at bought me a (medium-"end") usb-hub that I can use to deploy my changes to all the phones - but most of the time the phones are all empty because they were just laying the in drawer for a while. Keeping them connected to the USB-Hub while the computer is not attached does not charge them sufficiently. The usb-hub is also not capable of charging 4 drained out phone simulatinously.

**TL/DR - What I am looking for**

I am looking for a Multiport (aprox. 8 port) charger that is capable of:

- charging(!) the phones (plural!) while the computer is not conected
- is able to be used as a USB-Hub
- transfering data with a decent speed (at least usb 2.0)
- in the best case it also charges(!) the devices faster then the mac could while the mac is connected

So far I could only find either good Charger or good hubs. Not both.

Comment: Hi Welcome to Hardware Recs! [According to Apple Support computers equipped with USB 3 only provide up to 900 mA and 1100 mA if a compatible device is plugged in directly](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204377). Most low end android phones can take up to 1600 mA, with fast charging taking over 2000 mA. If you really want to fast charge 4+ phones quickly is it okay if this hub plugs into the wall and the computer? Additionally I noticed you marked your location as "Leipzig, Germany". Does the product need to available there without VAT and import taxes?

Comment: For example [how about this 10 port wall plugged usb hub?](https://www.newegg.com/global/de/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA24G36F9485&cm_re=usb_hub-_-17-392-080-_-Product) It will set you back €51,99 + €15,98 shipping. It appears Germany does not have US specific VAT or import fees as far as I can tell.

Comment: The reviews are very very bad :D Anything more "professiona" ?

Comment: Sure, what would your upper price limit/budget be?

Comment: Aprox. 100 Euro - but I am looking. If 200 Euros is necessary it's also possible. My current problem is that I don't know what to search for

Answer (score 1):

### [Wavlink 7-Port USB 3.0 Superspeed Hub with 48W Power Adapter €25,99](https://www.newegg.com/global/de/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6PF6EM9309)

[image: Wavlink Hub]

I've had a pretty good experience with Wavlink products in the past. They seem to be good at delivering a premium look and feel without the premium price. It claims to be capable of

> Transfer data at speeds of up to 5 Gbps through 7 ports

and

> Compatible with the BC 1.2 charging standard, the 7-Port USB 3.0 Hub
>   can charge your devices up to 2.4A each port when being used as a
>   stand-alone charger with no host computer attached

- USB standard Support: 1,2,3.0
- Offline charging up to 5V/2.4A per port
- Power switches and LEDs for each port
- 12V/4A Power Adapter

**Oh and by the way, international shipping is free, so that's a nice plus.**